# Django Admin: How do I set the ordering of inline elements?

Tags: django, django-admin

With a normal ModelAdmin class I can set the ordering with:

```
ordering = ("field_name",)
```

There seems to be no option to set ordering for InlineModelAdmin. Is there a way to get the inline elements to sort by a particular field?

Answer (score 69):

This works now so you can just do something like:

```
class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = MyModel
   ordering = ("field_name",)
```

Comment: Day-Saver. Be careful to use the comma (",") when you only have onw field to sort because it is a Python tuple.

Comment: 7 years later, still useful in Django 2.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a ticket for this, with a patch here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13862

Don't know if it actually works, though.

---

**Update:** The ticket is marked as fixed.

Comment: See Rrrrrk ' s answer, it is actually working. I need this sorting separation of model and admin in one of my many to many relations. My through model field needs to be sorted user specific in the frontend, but in the backend I needed the normal sorting according to "name-attr."